# Does offline index rebuild of clustered or non-clustered index block user's SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE queries?

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, sql-server-2019, index-maintenance, index-rebuild

I understand that index rebuild requires schema stability (Sch-S) lock which means it will block any query that tries to do the schema modification (Sch-M).

Does an offline index rebuild of clustered or non-clustered index also block user's SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE queries?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that index rebuild requires schema stability (Sch-S) lock which means it will block any query that tries to do the schema modification (Sch-M).

You seem to have this backwards. Any operation that changes system metadata requires a schema modification (sch-m) lock at some stage. Regular user queries require at least schema stability (sch-s) even when running under read uncommitted isolation. See [schema locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide#schema) in the documentation.

> Does an offline index rebuild of clustered or non-clustered index also block user's SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE queries?

The documentation is not as clear as it could be about this in all places, but [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql#online---on--off--as-applies-to-rebuild_index_option) is relatively clear (emphasis added):

> An offline index operation that creates, rebuilds, or drops a clustered, spatial, or XML index, or rebuilds or drops a nonclustered index, acquires a Schema modification (Sch-M) lock on the table. **This prevents all user access to the underlying table during the operation.**